# How to Encode Thai Characters in R

Tags: r, unicode, rstudio

I have read in the text file using `read.table`.

```
group <- read.table("Sample_No2.txt", header = T, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = F)
```

When I click on the `group` variable, it returns characters, which are not in English (It is in Thai language), in weird character (Below figure).

How do I make the software recognize the language ?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: It should work, R has support for Thai. See if this works
`x <- "เรียน ทุกท่าน"`. If it doesn't it is probably your os that needs a language pack.

Comment: This is a known bug with the RStudio data viewer. https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200979588-Displaying-non-latin-characters-e-g-German-umlaute-in-the-data-viewer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set locale to Thai in order to enable reading Thai alphabet

```
Sys.setlocale(locale = "Thai")
```

i hope this is an answer you were looking for as everyone else

Answer (score 0):

I want to write a shapefile with some columns that contain only Thai letters. Other columns contain numerical and character data.

I imported a shapefile with columns that contains Thai letters. The Thai letters appear normally.

When I write the file to my hard drive using st_write(my_shapefile,"folder/my_shapefile.shp",delete_layer=TRUE) it only shows ??? in the column that should contain Thai letters. The ??? are shown in QGIS and in R (when importing the shp file again).

I tried: Sys.setlocale(locale = "Thai")
It gave me a "Warning: OS reports request to set locale to "Thai" cannot be honored[1]".

Comment: This is a question and should not be posted as an answer to another question.  Please see the guidelines for asking questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask